# How to add function/method with ref parameter to Dicitonary-object?

Tags: c#, function, dictionary, methods, reference

To avoid a bigger switch-case-block, I would like to **add** (anonymous) **functions or methods to a Dictionary**. There are already alot explanations to that process. However, the functions/methions I am trying to store **MUST take a referenced parameter**:

```
private static Dictionary<int, Func<ref object, string, bool>> someMethDict = 
    new Dictionary<int, Func<ref object, string, bool>>(){};

public static void Init ()
{
    someMethDict.Add(0, someMeth);
}

public static bool someMeth (ref object obj, string param)
{
    // do something
    return true;
}
```

This code example does not compile because the `ref`-keyword is an invalid token in the Dictionary-instantiation.

So, how can I seduce the compiler in proper C# to store these methods with referenced parameters into my Dictionary? Although I used the Init-method above, to fill in the Dictionary, is there a way to instantiate it directly with the functions/methods stored in it under these circumstances?

Help is appreciated!

Comment: You can not access non static member inside static member `someMethDict.Add(0, someMeth);`

Comment: Also `someMeth` does not match the signature of defined delegate.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya You are right. I missed the static at ``someMeth``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare your own delegate type:

```
delegate bool MyDelegate (ref object obj, string param)
```

I hope I got the syntax right. It's been a long while since I last used this feature of the C# language. Since the `Func` types were introduced this is rarely useful.

Comment: This will work. A solution in C# where you could instantatiate the Dictionary directly with the function-definitions inside would have been nice, though. Not, it is readable but the Init-method must be called first get it all working.

Comment: What do you mean by "instantatiate the Dictionary directly with the function-definitions"? You can use a collection initializer. That makes the syntax more compact and no Init method is necessary.

Comment: Mh, ok, I am using collection initializers already in a slightly different contect (without the delegate). I am quite surprised that something like ``{EffectChangesEnum.Description, delegate(ref EffectChangesEnum def, string param){}}`` actually works.